# I've deleted some cells and cleared everything out and it keeps reverting back to DATE format

Tags: microsoft-excel, conversion, formatting, cells

I've never changed formatting to date: I always keep it in General unless I need to make it different.

Since my last Update, everything now changes to date when I either copy, paste, or when I delete or clear a bunch of cells - it goes back to DATE.  I don't have it selected to open or start in DATE format.  Help!

Comment: format cells as Text

Answer (score 0):

1. Open up an entirely unrelated spreadsheet.
2. Copy out what you want to that blank spreadsheet.

   - I would suggest that when you paste your click the clipboard that appears and make sure you select an option that does not include formatting. Such as "keep Values only"
3. On the new spreadsheet (just the copied data) right click and format with the type of data you're dealing with.
4. Back on the original spreadsheet. Delete out the data that you have copied over.
5. Go ahead and right-click and format to the correct data type (or general)
6. Go get your copied data from the temporary spreadsheet.

   - Don't use the Ctrl-V option. Right click and either select "Paste Values" which is the "123" option
   - or if you are pasting formulas, Select "Past Formulas" which is the fancy "F"

Comment: did this work for you?